# PHP: Is there any practical limit to the length of the input string for MD5 hashing?

Tags: php, hash, md5

I'm storing some passwords in a database using PHP+MySQL

I realise that MD5 is not a secure method to store passwords, but for now I'm using it mainly to ensure that regardless of the length of the password, it can be stored in the database easily.

For that I'm hashing the password using PHP and storing it in the database.

Is there any practical limit on the length of a password I can store using this manner?

(security is not of importance here, I am using the hashing only for convenience)

Comment: It is a password. People are likely to reuse it on other sites. Security *is* of importance.

Comment: As long as you realize that the longer the string, the more time it will take to process, you'll be fine.  And realistically, the time difference will not be noticeable for strings the length of standard passwords.

Comment: @Quentin The site isnt publicly accessible, and is only a prototype which is not going to be used in real life

Comment: Prototype code has a nasty habit of slipping in to production and/or being learned from … and it isn't as if using a save hash function is more work then using an unsafe one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you do not have to limit the length. PHP already contains some safety checks on the maximum request size to avoid malicious users from filling up your memory.

But as you mentioned: MD5 is NOT ACCEPTABLE to hash passwords. Neither is any other hashing algorithm unless you use it with a **salt**!